# Jquery Accordion does not fill height of container if container is rendered invisible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion inside a div and the heightstyle set to fill and the div is 100% in height.  It's a side panel with a help page inside.

When I render the page with the side panel visible, the accordion fills the entire space, top to bottom and that's great.  But when I render the panel invisible, and let the user make it visible, the accordion is all squished at the top and doesn't fill the entire space.

```
$('#helpaccordion').accordion({
               collapsible: true,
               header: 'h4',
               heightStyle: 'fill',
               active: parseInt(helpactivegroup),
               activate: function( event, ui ) {setActiveGroup()}
             });
```

Is there some way to refresh the accordion after it's been made visible?  Or some other way to ensure that it fills the entire space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

```
$("#helpaccordion").accordion("resize");
```

I just added this code, right after I initialized the accordion (even though it's still invisible at that point) and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

accordion do have a refresh method : [jQuery UI accordion API](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh)

Comment: I noticed that the resize method accomplishes the same thing, but it sounds like refresh is specifically designed for this purpose.  Would using refresh be better than resize for some reason?